# Validation Accuracy does not Imporve

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm facing a problem that my validation accuracy doess not imporve during training

this is my model structure:

```
def parkinson_detection_model(input_shape=(128, 128, 1)):
    regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), name='conv1', activation='relu', 
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((9, 9), strides=(3, 3)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), name='conv2', activation='relu', 
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((7, 7), strides=(3, 3)))
    
    

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), name='conv4', activation='relu', 
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))    
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='fc1'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='fc3'))
    
    optimizer = Adam(3.15e-5)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

and the results is like this :

Epoch 1/30 67/67 [==============================] - 76s 1s/step - loss: 0.8200 - accuracy: 0.5019 - val_loss: 0.8156 - val_accuracy:
0.4692
Epoch 2/30 67/67 [==============================] - 83s 1s/step - loss: 0.8116 - accuracy: 0.5217 - val_loss: 0.8074 - val_accuracy: 0.4692
Epoch 3/30 67/67 [==============================] - 80s 1s/step - loss: 0.8044 - accuracy: 0.4877 - val_loss: 0.7996 - val_accuracy: 0.4692
Epoch 4/30 67/67 [==============================] - 79s 1s/step - loss: 0.7968 - accuracy: 0.5038 - val_loss: 0.7938 - val_accuracy: 0.4692
Epoch 5/30 67/67 [==============================] - 75s 1s/step - loss: 0.7902 - accuracy: 0.5095 - val_loss: 0.7878 - val_accuracy: 0.4692

can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I think this is a question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: anyway I think that you are wrong because you are using a `categorical_crossentropy` instead a binary crossentropy. You have only two class. change loss function and replace you output layer with `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='fc3'))`

Answer (score 2):

Several things are wrong in your model.

1. Change your output layer/loss function depending on your problem (E.g.: Use an output layer with 2 neurons and a softmax activation or with 1 neuron with a sigmoid activation and a binary crossentropy loss).
2. Tune your learning rate (3.15e-5 is really small).
3. Good practice when using convolution layers is to start with a few `filters` and increase the value after each pooling layer. E.g.: Conv2D with 32 filters -> pooling -> Conv2D with 64 filters -> pooling -> Conv2D with 128 filters.
4. A dropout rate of 0.5 can be a high value.
5. For downsampling, simply use `MaxPooling2D((2, 2))` works.